# How to update the BLOB column in Oracle database with java

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to update the picture what I inserted into the database. I tried with `update` statement. But it produces error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

What I tried is:

```
 StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);
 sb.append("update ").append(uname).append("PROFILEPICTURE set PROFILEPICT=? where ID=1 for update");
 String query = sb.toString();
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
 ps.setBinaryStream(1, is);
```

I don't know how to update the BLOB content please anyone tell me how to update the BLOB column... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot issue an SQL statement "update ... for update". Just remove the trailing " for update" and your statement may work.

Since you don't tell us the content of `uname`, there may of course be other problems with your statement as well.